# Why did my Nexus 4 download the Jelly Bean 4.3 update again?

Tags: nexus-4, ota-update, 4.3-jelly-bean

I've got a stock, non-rooted Nexus 4 which I updated to Jelly Bean 4.3 when the OTA update came out a month or more ago. Just today I got another message that there was a system update available. It said it would update to 4.3, and I double-checked (and took a screenshot), and  confirmed I already had it in "About phone."

Nonetheless, I went ahead with the update to get rid of the notification, and it went through the usual process. The before and after screenshots of the about screen confirm that I had the exact same Android, Baseband, and Kernel versions, as well as the same Build Number. I can't find any differences after the update. Does anyone know why this might have happened?

Before screenshot, taken 2013-08-23 16:28:04, before the update was started about a minute later:

[image]

After screenshot, taken 2013-08-23 16:36:14 after the update finished and it restarted.

[image]

Comment: are you sure it is not an update to 4.3? They do release patches to the OS that do not increase the "major/minor" (4.3) version numbers.

Comment: @RyanConrad - That's what I thought before I did the update, and in order to figure out the difference, took the before and after screenshots. It seemed pretty weird when they were 100% identical. I'll add them to the question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> The before and after screenshots of the about screen confirm that I had the exact same Android, Baseband, and Kernel versions, as well as the same Build Number

Actually, they do not. The first screenshot shows a build number of JWR66**V**, and the second is JWR66**Y**. An official changelog has not been released, but [T-Mobile's documentation](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/08/20/t-mobile-posts-nexus-4-update-jwr66y-brings-security-improvements-probably-not-much-else/) indicates that the update contains "security" updates. You can also find some (unofficial) discussion of the actual code commits [in this article](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/08/22/developer-changelog-aosp-updated-with-the-latest-round-of-4-3-fixes-including-both-jwr66y-4-3_r1-1-and-jss15q-4-3_r2-2/). So although the version number was not incremented, it is a different build than you previously had.

Comment: Sharp eye indeed...can't believe I missed that. I was comparing them on my phone by flipping them back and forth in the gallery, but apparently I need to pay more attention. Thanks.

Comment: Also: http://www.cultofandroid.com/40006/android-4-3-security-update-rolls-out-to-nexus-4-galaxy-nexus/